# Uninstalling Skype 4.1 from 12.10

Tags: 12.10, skype

I want to completely uninstall Skype 4.1 from the terminal.  How do I do that.  Also, do I have to delete anything else to make sure I have removed it completely?

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge skype`?

Answer (score 13):

From the terminal, run:

```
sudo apt-get purge skype*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then you can remove the config files:

```
rm -fr ~/.Skype
```

That should do it.

Comment: I did this but now when I boot up a pop up window appears asking me to agree or disagree to the Skype terms of service.

Comment: run `cd / && find | sudo grep -i skype`. this will take a while but will show all files that include the name "skype." You can choose to remove them if you want. You should also check your "Startup Applications" to make sure skype is deselected.

Answer (score 3):

I tried

```
sudo apt-get purge skype*
sudo apt-get autoremove

rm -fr ~/.Skype
```

Nothing worked, only this did

> sudo dpkg -r skype:i386

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try also this:

```
wget -O skype http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.8-1_i386.deb 
sudo apt-get install libxss1
sudo dpkg -i skype
sudo apt-get -f install && sudo rm skype
```

This might work.

Comment: are you sure that you want to answer with "this MIGHT work"?

Answer (score -1):

This did for me

```
sudo apt-get purge skype-bin
```

Answer (score -2):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin
```

Comment: `purge`, not `remove`. OP wants to remove it completely, `remove` keeps configuration files and possibly some other stuff.