# How do I remove Skype 4.3 from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32-bit)

Tags: software-center, uninstall, skype

I installed Skype on my nephew's new Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine, and now we've decided to remove it. But I'm not able to locate it in my Installed programs section of Ubuntu Software Center. I'm able to call it up by opening the debian package, Software Center opens it up, but where I would normally see the "Remove" button, I have a "Reinstall" button. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to uninstall Skype. Any suggestions? In case you're wondering I used the version of Skype designed for 12.xx, as there was no option available for Ubuntu 14.xx.

Comment: post the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep 'skype'`

Comment: Update Or Uninstall Skype In Ubuntu http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/03/update-skype-ubuntu/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To uninstall completely Skype from your system you just type the following line in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge skype
```

And next time if you decide to install Skype again, follow [How to install Skype 4.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3/488062#488062)

Comment: As @harts12 recommends we need to apply after ``sudo apt-get autoremove``. Which is correct, simply verify it by running ``sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`` and you will see something like:

``The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:`` ... (list of packages)... ``Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.``

Answer (score 65):

My case is something different, here i run two commands :-

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep 'skype'
```

output is :- skype-bin:i386                 install

So, to remove i run :-

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove skype-bin:i386
```

and after that i remove ".Skype" from home directory

Comment: While the "skypeforlinux" answer was correct for my particular use case, this shows me how in general to _find what I have installed_ as well as know how to remove it.

Comment: This uninstalls the Skype that does not work in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Answer (score 34):

In my case:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove skypeforlinux
```

Comment: I think this will remove the latest Skype 5.x and not 4.3.

Comment: sudo apt-get --purge remove skype-bin:i386           removed the old skype for me

Comment: This uninstalls the Skype that works properly in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes just doing :

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove skype
```

will not uninstall skype 4.3 version

Hence i would recommend doing :

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove skype:i386
```

and then going to home directory do "ctrl+H" and remove .skype folder...

Comment: skype:i386 did it even though I'm running a 64bit computer.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.2 as of the date of this answer.

Remove package:

```
sudo apt remove skypeforlinux
```

Remove config:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/skypeforlinux
```

Remove repo:

```
sudo rm -v /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-*
```

Comment: It is the best answer. I had saved config with bugs after reinstall and only this solution helped for me.

Answer (score 3):

Install and use Synaptic Package Manager, which you can find in Software Center to remove Skype. It is easy to manage installed/update/remove applications in this thing.
About Synaptic here - [Synaptic Package Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I removed skype

> dpkg --get-selections | grep 'skype'
>
> sudo apt-get --purge remove skypeforlinux

Answer (score 1):

I did the following pair of commands on Ubuntu 16.04.02 to get rid of Skype 4.3:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove skype
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The first by itself still left a fully functional Skype installation. Autoremove took finished removing Skype without needing to manually delete any directories.

Edit:
The answers using `skypeforlinux` are for the newer versions of Skype (e.g. Skype 5.3).

Answer (score 1):

As for me - I removed skype with this:

```
sudo dpkg --remove skypeforlinux
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed your skype from official skype then it will be

> sudo apt-get --purge remove skypeforlinux

If this not works then you need to check your skype name, run below command to check it :-

> dpkg --get-selections | grep 'skype'

output is :- skypelinux install

So, to remove i run :-

> sudo apt-get --purge remove skypeforlinux

If you have installed it from software centre then you can un-install it from there also.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get purge skype-bin`

Only removing `skype` didn't work for me.