# I can't uninstall skype completely

Tags: skype

I tried to uninstall skype from the terminal and i think I already did because it says it cannot locate the package however when i turn the wifi off and on my skype contacts who are online appears at the bottom right of the screen and whenever I get a message I am still notified. I tried to search skype from my files but I cannot even find it and when I try to purge or remove it, it says unable to locate package. Help me!!!!!

i installed it by following the steps here: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Skype-Using-Terminal-on-Ubuntu then i uninstalled it by sudo apt-get purge skype.

Comment: How did you install skype?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Skype-Using-Terminal-on-Ubuntu i followed the steps here.

Comment: Okay. And how did you try to uninstall it? What did you do exactly - commands? Kindly edit your question to include this info.

Comment: Update Or Uninstall Skype In Ubuntu  http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/03/update-skype-ubuntu/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove Skype 4.3 from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32-bit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513657/how-do-i-remove-skype-4-3-from-ubuntu-14-04-lts-32-bit)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, one command at a time:
**Disclaimer: I don't have access to an Ubuntu machine and so can't test these out.**

```
sudo apt-get purge skype

sudo apt-get autoremove
rm -rf ~/.skype
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
sudo dpkg --remove skype
sudo dpkg --remove getskype-*
```

Comment: i did that but it says unable to locate file.

Comment: @ZcYhel After which command?

Comment: after the first one it says unable to locate

Comment: That's expected since you already removed it, just continue with the others.

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: @ZcYhel Do the contacts and notifications still show?

Comment: @ZcYhel  Kindly run this command and provide the result by editing your question `sudo dpkg --list skype`

Comment: it says no packages found matching skype.

Comment: @ZcYhel And the notifications still show? That's now weird..

Comment: @ZcYhel: Please try this command: `dpkg -l | grep skype`

Comment: @Parto The first two commands should be `sudo apt-get --purge remove skype` & `sudo apt autoremove`.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, so it might be different in previous versions.

Comment: It works in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

In Lubunt 18.06 this command completely uninstalled Skype:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove skypeforlinux
```