# Distorted sound from headphone jack Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones, jack

I am reaching out for a help to diagnose and to fix the problem I am having on my Ubuntu box.

The OS: Linux 3.16.0-51-generic #69~14.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux Desktop with default Unity Desktop environment.

Faulty hardware ruled out. 
The sound out of the Headphones Jack worked with no issue before updating from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.04.1 via apt-get dist-upgrade.

The Issue: When headphones are connected to a headphones jack, sounds comes out distorted, seems like in a mono (once channel) When that takes place, channel balance controls (L-R) are inaccessible in control panel.

All applications producing the sounds affected in the same way.

When headphones removed from a headphone jack, sounds returns to build-in internal speakers of the laptop with no issues (normal sounding stereo). HDMI connected external monitor/TV producing sounds just as expected with no issues.

This bug seems to be isolated just to headphone jack handling by OS.

If anyone knows the solution to resolve this FOR SURE, please share.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where exactly is the distortion? Low, middle, upper range?

Comment: It's not specific to a frequency. It's just distorted, badly. You can sort of hear sound, but it sounds very week while there is very loud and distorted picks from whatever is been played. It's the same with local mp3 files, videos or streaming content in the browser. As soon as you remover the headphones from the jack, built in speakers work just fine. When you re-insert the headphones - sounds terrible.    Looking in the control panel and "testing" the headphones "left" "right" produces the sounds in both channels (as mono). When you start playing anything in stereo - sounds goes bad.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lenovo g700 and sometimes I had the same problem. I notice that this was happening when I was booting on windows 8  (dual boot). After that my sound was distorted, not every time. When I reboot again to Ubuntu it was working fine. Hope that help you also!

Answer (score -1):

I had very similar problem.

**I completely removed Skype** and audio jacks, both input and output, started working normally

Apparently, the whole problem was my Skype installation.

Comment: Also had a severe distortion problem with headset on Ubuntu 16.04, Dell Precision. Internal speakers were fine. As for the [other poster][2], the problem was immediately resolved when I removed `skypeforlinux` (see for example [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/888409/527764)). [2]: https://askubuntu.com/a/732684/527764